# Jquery - Javascript : Create a Carousel OF Carousels

Tags: jquery, animation, carousel, caroufredsel

Usually, I can do whatever I want with CarouFredsel plugin (http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) but I didn't find a way to make this work: I try to create a jquery carousel **of** carousels to switch nicely from a carousel to another.

With CarouFredsel, I'm able to have several carousels next to the other and switch to the next one with a jquery animation, but it's not smooth as carouFredsel can be due to the different div heights.

Maybe another plugin can do the job?

Comment: you could use malsup jquery cycle plugin to cycle divs around your CarouFredsel instances so slide between them

Answer (score 0):

I like **[bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/)** a lot for making responsive carousels.  Check it out!

I know from experience that it is possible to nest bxSliders within one another, although you have to do a little extra work for it (disabling pagers/controls on outer carousel and manually binding the next and previous slide API methods to your controls `click` event instead).